# ArrayOutOfBounds Exception (registration program)

Tags: java, arrays, oop

I'm trying to write this Registration Program for Sports Teams, but when I input a name and age which qualifies for a team, an `java.lang.ArrayOutOfBoundsException` occurs. Any idea why? The code and classes can be seen below.

The objective of the code is to fill out arrays in the Team Class, and print it out once the user inputs '3' in the Test Class.

```java
public class Member {
    public String name;
    public int age;
   
    public Member(String name, int age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}

public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choi;
        Team basketball = new Team("Basketball", 2, 18, 21);
        Team volleyball = new Team("Volleyball", 3, 17, 19);
        
         do{
        //MENU
        System.out.println("Select Team");
        System.out.println("--------------");
        System.out.println("[1] Basketball");
        System.out.println("[2] Volleyball");
        System.out.println("[3] Exit");
        System.out.println("---------------");
        System.out.print("Choice: ");
        
        choi = myScan.nextInt();
        myScan.nextLine();  
        
        //SWITCH START
        switch(pili){
           
            //BASKETBALL CASE
            case 1:
                String name;
                int age;
                
                System.out.println("Basketball");
                System.out.print("Enter Name: ");
                name = myScan.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Enter Age: ");
                age = myScan.nextInt();
                myScan.nextLine();
                
                Member bball = new Member(name,age);
                basketball.addMember(bball);
                
                break;
                
            //END CASE 1
                
            //VOLLEYBALL CASE
            case 2:
                String name1;
                int age1;
                
                System.out.println("Volleyball");
                
                System.out.print("Enter Name: ");
                name1 = myScan.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Enter Age: ");
                age1 = myScan.nextInt();
                
                
                Member vball = new Member(name1, age1);
                volleyball.addMember(vball);
                
                
                break;
            //END CASE 2
                
                
            //EXIT CASE
            case 3:
            
                System.out.println("Basketball Team Members");
                for(int i = 0; i<2; i++){
                    System.out.println(basketball.members[i]);
                }
                System.out.println("Volleyball Team Members");
                for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
                    System.out.println(volleyball.members[i]);
                }
            break;
            //CASE 3 END
                
             } //END SWITCH
        
        } //END DO
        while(choi > 0 && pili < 3);
    }


    public class Team {
    
    public String name;
    public int memberCnt;
    public int maxMember;
    public Member [] members = new Member[maxMember]; 
    public int minAge;
    public int maxAge;
    
    public Team(String name, int maxMember, int minAge, int maxAge){
        this.name = name;
        this.maxMember = maxMember;
        this.minAge = minAge;
        this.maxAge = maxAge;
    }
    
    public void addMember(Member memb){
        
      boolean result = checkQualification(memb); 
        
      if(memberCnt < maxMember){
          if (result){
            members[memberCnt]=memb;
            memberCnt++;
            System.out.println("Welcome to the " + name);
        }
         else{
            System.out.println("You are not qualified!");
        }
      }
      else{
          System.out.println(name + " Team is no longer accepting applicants");
      } 
    }
    
  
     public boolean checkQualification(Member memb){
        
        return memb.age >= minAge && memb.age <= maxAge; 
    }   
}
```

Comment: Instead of writing in the question that given answer solved your problem, you should mark the answer as accepted by cliking the gray check mark beside the answer. That's the correct way of telling everyone that this answer works for you. Have a look here:  [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

The error is because of

```
public int maxMember;
public Member[] members = new Member[maxMember];
```

Because at this moment `maxMember` values `0`, so you're creating an empty array

---

Do the instantiation when you have the real value of `maxMembers`, in the constructor

```
public int maxMember;
public Member[] members;

public Team(String name, int maxMember, int minAge, int maxAge) {
    this.name = name;
    this.maxMember = maxMember;
    this.members = new Member[maxMember];
    this.minAge = minAge;
    this.maxAge = maxAge;
}
```

---

Attribut `maxMembers` could not be an attribut, and you would use array's length in condition

```
if (memberCnt < members.length) {
```